# curl and cookies php

Tags: php, curl, cookies

i'm french and i need some help. 
So I'd like to make a php script with cURL library and the goal of this script is to add a article in the basket on a website's shop but between the moment when I add  the article and when I pay it the script failed the session. I've tried to save the cookies but that doesn't work! I don't understand! Could you please answer me if you have any idea about how i could make it works
my code is

```
<?php

    function login($url,$data){
    $fp = fopen("cookie.txt", "w");
    fclose($fp);
    $login = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "cookie.txt");
    //curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookie.txt");
    curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 40000);
    curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
    curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
    ob_start();
    return curl_exec ($login);
    ob_end_clean();
    curl_close ($login);
    unset($login);    
}                  
function grab_page($site){
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 40);
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookie.txt");
    curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $site);
    ob_start();
    return curl_exec ($ch);
    ob_end_clean();
    curl_close ($ch);
}


login('link','data to add in basket');
echo grab_page(the basket);
?>
```

Comment: I've wrote this [package](https://packagist.org/packages/w3zone/crawler) which i think it will help you to handle your requests.

Comment: i don't understand how it's work ?

Answer (score 0):

you are mixing the curl handlers,

in your login function you are using `$ch` handler

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
//          ^^^
```

which is must be `$login`

```
curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
```

the same, in your `grab_page` function you are using `$login`

```
curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
//          ^^^^^^
```

which is must be:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
```